# how to order the table by sorting a given column with some specific format

Tags: r, statistics

I have a data table generated as follows:

```
df<-read.table("C:\\Desktop\\ID.txt",header=FALSE, sep=",")
df.table<-data.frame(df)
```

The data looks like this

```
A              B                      C
1   2016-04-08 21:51:19.232000000    4624
2   2016-04-08 21:51:20.232000000    4623
3   2016-04-08 21:51:23.223000000    4646
4   2016-03-08 21:51:23.224000000    4624
5   2016-04-08 21:51:23.210000000    4625
6   2016-02-08 21:51:24.251000000    4648
```

I would like to order this table following the sorted order of B column

```
A               B                     C
6   2016-02-08 21:51:24.251000000    4648
4   2016-03-08 21:51:23.224000000    4624
1   2016-04-08 21:51:19.232000000    4624
2   2016-04-08 21:51:20.232000000    4623
5   2016-04-08 21:51:23.210000000    4625
3   2016-04-08 21:51:23.223000000    4646
```

May I know how to do that?

Comment: `read.table` produces a data.frame, so there's no need to coerce. Also, if `sep = ','`, you could just use `read.csv`, though it does have slightly different defaults (notably `header = TRUE`). Regardless, you should format your datetime column with your favorite format, e.g. `df$B <- as.POSIXct(df$b, tz = 'UTC')`.

Comment: It seems to me that changing it to "UTC" will remove the tail string, like 223000000, I need to keep it to separate 2016-04-08 21:51:23.210000000  and 2016-04-08 21:51:23.223000000

Comment: UTC is just the time zone; it won't affect seconds. They're there, even if it doesn't print them in its display format. You can set the `options(digits.secs = 6)` (or whatever you like) if you'd like it to print more digits, though; see `?DateTimeClasses`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `order` on the POSIXct column

```
dfN <- df1[order(df1$B),]
dfN
#  A                       B    C
#6 6 2016-02-08 21:51:24.250 4648
#4 4 2016-03-08 21:51:23.223 4624
#1 1 2016-04-08 21:51:19.232 4624
#2 2 2016-04-08 21:51:20.232 4623
#5 5 2016-04-08 21:51:23.210 4625
#3 3 2016-04-08 21:51:23.223 4646
```

Here, I assumed that the column 'B' is in `POSIXct` class or else, we may need to convert it to that `class` before we `order`

```
options(digits.secs = 4)
df1$B <- as.POSIXct(df1$B )
```